# Trouble in call command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, notepad

I'm usually stuck on making a game now...I can't solve the the call command problem This is an example :::

```
:verifile1
    cls
    echo.
    echo Before you can continue give out the following information...
    echo.
    echo What is your username?
    echo.
    set /p name1=Username:
    if not exist "%name1%_1.bat" (
        echo Invalid Username
        pause>nul
        goto welcome
    )
    echo.
    echo Your password?
    echo.
    set /p pass1=Password:
    call label %name1%_1.bat
    if not %password1% EQU %pass1% (
        echo Password entered do not match
        pause>nul
        goto welcome
    )
    goto Story
```

Please help me with this case

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: What's the error? Or what should it do but it doesn't? One thing that doesn't look right is `call label %name1%_1.bat`....Are you calling a label (coincidentally named _label_) or a batch?

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling a label then call it thus

```
Call :Label arg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
call label %name1%_1.bat
```

calls an utility named [label](http://ss64.com/nt/label.html) (yes, there happens to be one...) and gives it `%name1%_1.bat` as parameter. Probably not *quite* what you want.

To call a label inside your batchfile, use:

```
call :label
```

But I guess, you simply want to call your second batchfile `%name1%_1.bat`. To do so, simply:

```
call %name1%_1.bat
```